# Story of a whale shepherd who pilots a submarine to herd them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a guy that pilots a submarine and kind of shepherds whales and protect them from killer whales attacks. I don't remember much else.

Just it was a short story or tale and almost sure it's Philip K Dick's, but I can't find it looking through his work, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Mentioned [here](https://www.ukclimbing.com/forums/culture_bunker/how_do_you_define_sci_fi-195997); *"i read a sci-fi short story once in which a 'whale shepherd' was dinking around in his little submarine protecting the 'herd' from sharks with his dolphins - that sort of thing - we could start doing that in a few years with no new technology but it's definitely sci-fi i'd say"*

Comment: There's a short story/novella called "The Whale Shepherd" mentioned [here](http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/printheritage/detail/846e8925-d552-40e8-8fec-96e992df9242.aspx). I can't find a copy/review online;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [The Deep Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deep_Range) by Arthur C. Clarke, based on a [short story of the same name](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41491).

> **Don Burley is a whale shepherd, keeping the herds safe from predators.**
> He gets unwillingly pulled off that job and asked to train the
> mysterious Walt Franklin, a former spacer with some undisclosed past
> incident that left him subject to panic attacks. The men eventually
> come to enjoy a friendship based on mutual respect and shared
> adventures in the deep ranges of the world's oceans. So you get plenty
> of suspense, some tragedy, love stories, and another glimpse of a
> possible future. The underwater scenes were breathtaking, even for me
> who likes to stay on dry land.

Comment: My first thought as well, +1.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - The question is a bit terse to be sure. And frankly, if I was going to write a story about a whale shepherd, I'd throw in a killer whale attack, so that's not much help!